# Quantum Mechanics for beginners

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I am new to Quantum Mechanics, and very much eager to know the secret of it but I don't know from which book I could read. I wonder how the equations are predicted and as well as understand all the physical significance and the concept.I am from India, a student of 11th standard.I have learned calculus but do not know anything about vector space or (Analytical Algebra), in Physics I am well equipped with Mechanics, and other topics of electricity and magnetism. 
Please suggest a good book.

Comment: *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* by Griffiths is one of the most accessible resources out there:
https://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Quantum-Mechanics-David-Griffiths/dp/0131118927

Comment: There's no way to answer this appropriately unless you tell us something about your background in math and physics.

Comment: I agree but in the case that you do know a good bit of maths this is an excellent text https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04361.pdf

Comment: @cal: The Anchordoqui paper you linked,https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04361 ,  to is horrifically bad IMO. I feel sorry for anyone who tries to learn qm from it, regardless of their background.